# spring-data-neo4j with maven-compiler-plugin and xlint causes compiler warning

Tags: spring-data-neo4j, maven-compiler-plugin

I've been tasked with integrating the spring-data-neo4j Maven dependency into a project that uses the maven-compiler-plugin with Xlint and the -Werror flag. I'm having some compiling problems which I need to fix.

Building a Maven project that relies on spring-data-neo4j and this build configuration issues a compilation warning which causes the build to fail. I'm not at liberty to change the build configuration of this project, so I'm trying to find a way to eliminate the compiler warning.

I have reproduced the issue by forking the http://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-data-neo4j project to https://github.com/spencerhrob/gs-accessing-data-neo4j.

In the **with-xlint** branch, the pom.xml file "build" section has been changed to the following:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <debug>true</debug>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <Xlint/>
                    <Werror />
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Running **mvn clean package** in the **complete** folder in this branch returns the following compilation error:

```
[WARNING] COMPILATION WARNING :  
[INFO]-------------------------------------------------------------  
[WARNING] No processor claimed any of these annotations: org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean, org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.EnableNeo4jRepositories, org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.NodeEntity,org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.GraphId,org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.RelatedTo,org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.Fetch,org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration,org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
[INFO] 1 warning    
[INFO]------------------------------------------------------------- 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------- 
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :   
[INFO]------------------------------------------------------------- 
[ERROR] warnings found and -Werror specified [INFO] 1 error
```

By removing the -Xlint flag (as in the **without-xlint** branch) predictably causes the compiler warning to not be issued. Also, removing the -Werror flag (as in the **without-werror** branch) causes the warning to be issued, but the Maven build still completes successfully.

I've also tried using Xlint with the spring-boot-maven-plugin build plugin as used in the parent gs-accessing-data-neo4j project. The **without-maven-compiler-plugin** branch in my repository has the following configuration:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <debug>true</debug>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <Xlint/>
                    <Werror />
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Running **mvn clean package** on this branch returns no compiler warnings even though Xlint is specified in the compiler arguments (though I admit I'm not completely sure Xlint is running).

I know that I can resolve this problem by removing the maven-compiler-plugin or by removing the -Xlint or -Werror flags, but that isn't an option because I can't change the build configuration for the project I'm working on (which is not the referenced GitHub repository).

Is there a known reason why building a spring-data-neo4j dependent project using maven-compiler-plugin with -Xlint and -Werror flags causes the "No processor claimed any of these annotations" compiler warning? And, is there a way to eliminate the compiler warning without removing the maven-compiler-plugin or the -Xlint and -Werror flags?